# Is it possible to 'freeze panes' in SharePoint lists?

Tags: sharepoint, list, listview

I need to keep my columns header, so people can see what data is displayed there, but I can not find if it is possible, or how to do it. Also will be nice to add a navigation bar to the list. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I had similar challenge recently, and worked out the following code. The code works for IE, but there's a problem with the width of the [freeze header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854632) in Chrome.

Anyway, hope it helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Replace 'NameOfList' with the name of the SharePoint list
  var $header = $("table[summary^='NameOfList']:first > tbody > tr.ms-viewheadertr"); 
  var headertop = $header.offset().top;

  // Replace 'NameOfColumn' with the name of the column that you would like to freeze
  var $fzCol= $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('NameOfColumn')");

  // IE has iFrame, Chrome doesn't have, so the 'n-th' count of the column is different in IE than in Chrome 
  if( $fzCol.siblings().eq(0).children().eq(0).prop("tagName") == "IFRAME"){ var shift = 0} else { var shift = 1};
  var nfzCol=$fzCol.index()+shift;

  var $mcol=$("table[summary^='NameOfList'] > tbody > tr:not(.ms-viewheadertr) > td:nth-child("+nfzCol+")");
  var colleft=$mcol.eq(0).offset().left;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowtop = $('body').scrollTop();
    if( windowtop > headertop ){
      $header.css({"position":"absolute", "top":windowtop});
    } else {
      $header.css({"position":"static", "top":"0px"});
    }

    var windowleft = $('body').scrollLeft();
    if (windowleft > colleft ){
      $mcol.css({"position":"relative", "left": windowleft-colleft});
    } else {
      $mcol.css({"position":"static", "left":"0px"});
    }
  });
}
```